# Backbone.history has already been started issue

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm developing an app by backbone.js and phonegap and in logcat console of eclipse appear this error:

```
android.webkit.CallbackProxy 711<!> Uncaught Error: Backbone.history has already been  
started at file:///android_asset/www/libs/backbone/backbone%201.0.0.js:1363
```

The code that error indicate, is the  backbone library called by a loader.

This is the main.js where is an explicit call to Backbone.history:

```
require.config({
paths: {
    jQuery: '../libs/jquery/jquery-loader',
    jQueryMobile: '../libs/jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-loader',
    underscore: '../libs/underscore/underscore-loader',
    Backbone: '../libs/backbone/backbone-loader',<--error indicate this library
    order: '../libs/require/order-1.0.5',
    text: '../libs/require/text-1.0.6',
    async: '../libs/require/async',
    PhoneGap: '../libs/phonegap/phonegap-loader',
    Handlebars: '../libs/handlebars/Handlebars',
    templates: '../templates'
}
});

require(['order!jQuery'], function($) {


require(['underscore', 'Backbone', 'router'], function(_, Backbone, AppRouter) {



    document.addEventListener("deviceready", run, false);
     run();

    function run() {

        var sync = Backbone.sync;
    Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
    options.beforeSend = function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Parse-Application-Id',    
    '***S3VMk');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Parse-REST-API-Key', '**fIt1Gm');
    };



    sync(method, model, options);

    },


         Parse.$ = jQuery;


    Parse.initialize("***iTS3VMk",
               "***9qLN7Duy");





        app = new AppRouter();
        console.log("history");
        Backbone.history.start();<--explicit call



       }
  });
  });
```

backbone loader:

```
define(['../libs/backbone/backbone 1.0.0'],
function () {
    return Backbone.noConflict();
});
```

Comment: How does it look the content of ../libs/backbone/backbone-loader file?

Comment: Added backbone loader

Comment: This error can influence on application works?